# MATPLOTLIB - Datapoints sticking together on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot data on a line chart.

I managed to do that correctly according to the assignment, but I have a little problem. Instead of
having the dates on the x-axis, I have a continuous black line. It actually seems as all the dates
on the dataframe are applied on the chart, thus sticking together and making it one long line.

Here is my code

```
x = df['date']
y = df['value']

plt.figure(figsize=(18,8))
plt.title('Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Pageviews')

plt.plot(x, y, color = 'red', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

Can anybody give me a tip about that?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what data type are your `x` values?  i.e. what does printing `x.dtype` give?  I'd assume it's `O`/`object` or some string type like `<U12`.  presumably it should be `datetime64` for dates, if that's the case then you need to tell pandas to parse the column appropriately

Comment: x is an object and y is an int. Ok, I get it now, I should have parsed the data before. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your dataframe is something like:

```
           date     value
0    2020-01-01  2.160526
1    2020-01-02 -1.887699
2    2020-01-03  0.805389
3    2020-01-04 -0.680120
4    2020-01-05  0.658396
```

if you call:

```
print(df.info())
```

you should get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 366 entries, 0 to 365
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   date    366 non-null    object 
 1   value   366 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 4.4+ KB
None
```

Pay attention to Dtype of column `date`: it is `object`. This means pandas stores `date` values as `str`; so, first of all, you need to convert `str` to `datetime` with:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
```

where `'%Y/%m/%d'` depends on the format in which data are stored in your dataframe.
Now you should have:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 366 entries, 0 to 365
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   date    366 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   value   366 non-null    float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 5.8 KB
None
```

---

At this point, you can proceed with the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['date'], df['value'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can customize date ticks based on your needs with:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator(interval = 10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%B %d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)
ax.set_xlim([df['date'].iloc[0], df['date'].iloc[-1]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, especially for the ticks explanation, I was checking the documentation but I struggled with that. thanks a lot